# Javascript reg ex to match whole word only, bound only by whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

so I know \bBlah\b will match a whole Blah, however it will also match Blah in "Blah.jpg"  I don't want it to.  I want to match only whole words with a space on either side.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can try: `\sBlah\s`.

Or if you allow beginning and end anchors, `(^|\s)Blah(\s|$)`

This will match `"Blah"` by itself, or each `Blah` in `"Blah and Blah"`

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

  - `\s` stands for "whitespace character".
  - The caret `^` matches the position before the first character in the string
  - Similarly, `$` matches right after the last character in the string

---

#### Lookahead variant

If you want to match both `Blah` in `"Blah Blah"`, then since the one space is "shared" between the two occurrences, you must use assertions. Something like:

```
(^|\s)Blah(?=\s|$)
```

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

---

#### Capturing only `Blah`

The above regex would also match the leading whitespace.

If you want only `Blah`, ideally, lookbehind would've been nice:

```
(?<=^|\s)Blah(?=\s|$)
```

But since Javascript doesn't support it, you can instead write:

```
(?:^|\s)(Blah)(?=\s|$)
```

Now `Blah` would be captured in `\1`, with no leading whitespace.

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [flavor comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)

Comment: This does not match the second Blah in: "Blah something Blah." because of the dot. But there IS a space before it

Comment: Very useful. this helped me to strip single characters. Thanks a million.

Comment: It works good. But i have a another case "yes yes*** yes ***no ***no*** yes". In that case any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: (?:^|\s)(yes)(?=|$) woohoo

Answer (score 26):

Matching all:

```
\bBlah\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/plsuRb6Tm3eRqLPu)

Comment: There's no need to use alternation here, as `\b` includes both `^` and `$`. Lookahead is redundant here too, as `\b` matches not a character, but a boundary. So, a simple `\bBlah\b` does the same thing.

Comment: Great solution, but the answer could use an explanation. `\b` matches a word boundary:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#boundary-type_assertions

Answer (score 4):

extracting all words in a string

```
words_array = str.match(/\b(\w|')+\b/gim)   //only single qout allowed
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `\sBlah\s` — that will match any form of whitespace on either side.

Comment: See http://www.rubular.com/r/22vteB0NjK ; this may miss some matches, depending on what is desired.

Answer (score 1):

`(^|\s)Blah(\s|$)` should work, however it will also select the spaces, if you just want the word you can do this:
`(^|\s)(Blah)(\s|$)` and take group 2 ($2 in ruby).

If want help with a RegEx, checkout: http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: This may miss some matches, e.g. the last `Blah` here: http://www.rubular.com/r/xSCyF42ymy

Comment: You're correct, see commend above, to fix that, or end it with (?=\s|$)