# singling out words in a string

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, include

Basic question here!

We're creating a chat bot using JavaScript which responds to certain words contained in messages posted by users on the chat.

Currently it responds to:

```
if(input.includes('bot') {}
```

however this also makes it respond to other words such as "bother" "bottle" and so on. We have tried the following

```
if(input.includes('bot ') || input.includes(' bot ') || input.includes(' bot')) {}
```

which actually stops it from responding to the stand-alone word "bot" and still responds to sentences such as "we both are" (because of ' bot'h are)

It's been a while since I've programmed things and would like some help with this, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript reg ex to match whole word only, bound only by whitespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951915/javascript-reg-ex-to-match-whole-word-only-bound-only-by-whitespace)

Comment: List all the patterns of the strings that you want to match and then create a Regex. Like the patterns here could be ` bot bot. bot, ` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably do like this. This would also handle a proper check of your key ("bot" in this case) at the beginning or end of the sentences or when it followed by a comma, dot, exclamation mark, question mark etc.

```js
var msg1 = "Hello bot",
    msg2 = "Hello bottle",
     key = "bot",
       r = new RegExp("\\b"+key+"\\b");
console.log(r.test(msg1));
console.log(r.test(msg2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the chat message using `.split()` and then look if any of the words is "bot".

```
var msg = "Hello bot";

var mArr = msg.split(" ");

function contains(arr,word){
    for (i in arr){
        if (arr[i] === word){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

contains(mArr,"bot");//true
```

This is my early approach, you probably would also need to filter standalone "bot" or "bot," and such.